# Facebook iOS Login Returns isCancelled as True Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, facebook-login

I have been attempting to create a fb login in my application, the problem is that once logged in the isCancelled value of the FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult in the didCompleteWithResults is true. I have seen other people get this error but their problem was with their AppDelegate.swift which I see no problem with mine.

Here is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    var loginbutton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //facebook login
        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()==nil){
            println("Not Logged In..")
        }else{
            println("Logged In")
        }

    loginbutton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]
    loginbutton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+(self.view.frame.height/4))

    self.loginbutton.delegate = self
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)

    self.view.addSubview(loginbutton)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//Facebook Login
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if error==nil{
        println("declined:\(result.declinedPermissions)")
        println("granted:\(result.grantedPermissions)")
        println("isCan:\(result.isCancelled)")
        println("token:\(result.token)")
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    }else{
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
    import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
    import FBSDKLoginKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application:UIApplication, openURL url:NSURL, sourceApplicaiton:String?, annotation:AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplicaiton, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Comment: Which SDK are you using?